# C++ warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c++, string-literals

I am using gnuplot to draw a graph in C++. The graph is being plot as expected but there is a warning during compilation. What does the warning mean?

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

This is the function I am using:

```
void plotgraph(double xvals[],double yvals[], int NUM_POINTS)
{
    char * commandsForGnuplot[] = {"set title \"Probability Graph\"", 
        "plot     'data.temp' with lines"};
    FILE * temp = fopen("data.temp", "w");
    FILE * gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent ", "w");
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(temp, "%lf %lf \n", xvals[i], yvals[i]); 
        //Write the data to a te  mporary file
    }
    for (i=0; i < NUM_COMMANDS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "%s \n", commandsForGnuplot[i]); 
        //Send commands to gn  uplot one by one.
    }
    fflush(gnuplotPipe);
}
```

Comment: This is C, not C++

Comment: It means that in a future version this will be a compile error.

Comment: @Davidbrcz First, it's still valid C++ code though it's C-style. Second, changing the tag to C is incorrect because this is not a problem that would happen to C. In C, string literals are not of `const` type.

Comment: @Davidbrcz also please see [Retagging C++ questions as C without consulting asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker).

Comment: @YuHao indeed, I also added the relevant meta thread on this topic.

Comment: @Yu Hao: It is syntactically valid. However It is morally wrong to write that code and claim it is written in C++. If you had written this in my department, you would be immediately fired. 

My bad for retaging. But I still think it is wrong to let the C++ tag with it. This maintains the false idea you can do C++ like you do C. They are 2 separated languages and no questions should be tagged both because norms, idioms and tools are not the same. It is Either C either C++, not both.

Comment: It is not tagged both, it is tagged as C++.  Also, C++ supports many different paradigms. IMO if a program is correct and tidy there is no basis for saying that the code is wrong because a different paradigm should have been used. OP's code is easy to read and understand.

Comment: I am just astonished by some of the comments I read on these sites. This guy asks a perfectly reasonable question, and someone just jumps down his throat. Why not make a polite, constructive comment and then answer it? In the UK, if you fired someone for that, the person would probably have an excellent case for taking you to an employment tribunal.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

String literals are an *array of const char*, we can see this from the draft C++ standard section `2.14.5` *String literals* which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal **has type “array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

so this change will remove the warning:

```
const char * commandsForGnuplot[] = {"set title \"Probability Graph\"", "plot     'data.temp' with lines"};
^^^^^
```

Note, allowing a *non-const char** to point to *const* data is a bad idea since modifying a *const* or a *string literal* is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). We can see this by going to section `7.1.6.1` *The cv-qualifiers* which says:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified,
>   any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results
>   in undefined behavior.

and section `2.14.5` *String literals* which says:

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in
>   nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. The effect of
>   attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.