# ERROR deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++, string-literals

I'm stuck with error message deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

What I tried to do here is to assign "First", "Last" to cfoo1 and make cfoo2 equal to cfoo1. Lastly, display cfoo1 and cfoo2 to standard output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "cfoo.h"

using namespace std;

CFoo :: CFoo(char first[], char last[]){

    m_first[BUF] = first[BUF];
    m_last[BUF] = last[BUF];
}

void CFoo :: WriteFoo(){

    cout << m_first[BUF] << ", " << m_last[BUF];
}



#ifndef CFOO_HEADER
#define CFOO_HEADER

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int   BUF = 256;

class   CFoo{

    public:
        CFoo(char first[], char last[]);

        void WriteFoo();

    private:
        char    m_first[BUF];
        char    m_last[BUF];
};

#endif


#include <iostream>
#include "cfoo.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    CFoo    foo1("Jong", "Yoon");
    CFoo    foo2 = foo1;

    cout << "foo1 = ";
    foo1.WriteFoo();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "foo 2 = ";
    foo2.WriteFoo();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify string literals. Using a `char *` instead of `const char *` to point to them has no merit and the class might as well use `std::string` in the first place.

Comment: Related: [C++ warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529194/c-warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-wwrite-stri) ... maybe dup.

Comment: The assignments and printing also don't do what you seem to think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. Using string literals (which are of type `char const*`) to call a function that expects `char[]`.
2. Trying to assign to `char` arrays.

Fixes:

1. Change the constructor to:

   ```
   CFoo(char const* first, char const* last);
   ```
2. Change its implementation to:

   ```
   CFoo(char const* first, char const* last)
   {
     // Make sure to copy at most BUF-1 characters
     // to m_first and m_last.

     m_first[0] = '\0'
     strncat(m_first, first, BUF-1);

     m_last[0] = '\0'
     strncat(m_last, last, BUF-1);
   }
   ```

You also need to change the implementation of `CFoo::WriteFoo()` to use the entire string

```
void CFoo::WriteFoo()
{
    cout << m_first << ", " << m_last;
}
```

Also,

Accessing `m_first[BUF]` or `m_last[BUF]` is an error since the maximum value of a valid index to access those arrays is `BUF-1`.

Comment: it'd be wise to check the lengths before doing `strcpy`.

Comment: Oh other question. In main.cpp, I tried to change 
CFoo    foo2 = foo1; to const CFoo    foo2 = foo1;
I get error passing 'const CFoo' as 'this' argument of 'void CFoo::WriteFoo()' discards qualifiers.
can you explain about this error?

Comment: @pooya13, change `WriteFoo()` to a `const` function. Make that a habit. Any time you write a member function that does not modify the object, make it a `const` member function.