# Adding new field to a c++ vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, telegram

I am developing an app to send and receive packets.

I am working with the `std::vector` class (first I started making the packets in arrays and I am open to change the method if you suggest one better).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110509/how-to-elegantly-initialize-vectorchar-with-string-literal) smart function to add any `const char*` to a `vector` object. But I would like to do another one to add them between `{.. , ..}` like I can do in C#. Here an example:

```
vector<char*> packet;

char dest[] = { 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x61 };
AppendLiteral(packet, dest); //Ok

/*Or directly:*/ AppendLiteral(packet, { 10, 10, 0, 20 }); //But this does not work
```

Is it possible in c++? I know in C# you can do something like this.

Edit:

A possible solution is:

```
vector<uint8> telegram;

vector<uint8> src = { 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x20 };
vector<uint8> dst = { 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x60 };

telegram.insert(telegram.end(), dst.begin(), dst.end());
telegram.insert(telegram.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
```

With a little function to write less:

```
template <typename T>
void Append(vector<T> *data, vector<T> *data2)
{
    data->insert(data->end(), data2->begin(), data2->end());
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: Are you sure the numbers in the last line aren't being parsed as if they were `int`s?

Comment: I've found a method: using vectors and using the function `insert`. I've created a new function too: `void Append(vector<T> *data, vector<T> *data2)
{
 data->insert(data->end(), data2->begin(), data2->end());
}`

Answer (score 3):

Your `vector<char*>` just contains pointers to variables of type `char`. It does not contain any data. This is dangerous, because said pointer can become dangling if the objects pointed to go out of scope.

Better use a data type as element type for your `vector`. If you want to store strings, use `std::vector<std::string>`. If you want to hold objects like `char[4]`, use `std::vetor<std::array<char,4>>`. If you want to hold arrays of bytes of arbitrary length, use `std::vetor<std::vector<char>>`.

```
int main()
{
  using packet=std::array<char,4>; // also works with packet=std::string
                                   //              or packet=std::vector<char>

  std::vector<packet> packets;

  packets.push_back({0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x61});
  packets.push_back({10, 10, 0, 20});

  packet p={0x2,0x4,0xa,0xb};
  packets.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: I see, I will do it. Thanks

Comment: I've tried this but it seems not work. How would you join two arrais?

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? Be more specific. Also, you keep on changing your question -- that's bad, because it is hard to hit a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

```
std::vector<std::array<char, 4>> packet;
```

Try this one.

Comment: I am not used to code a lot in c++ so I copied pasted the code in my program and I have got an ambiguous template parameter error with T. I am adding hexadecimal values so I don't know if char type is the optimal (in C# I use byte arrays)

Comment: What I want is if I have this arrays (telegram header) [01,00,01,01,00] I would like to add this other two [10,01] for example, I do not know if you know what I mean.

Comment: The packet does not only have 4 fields, I would like to add strings as long as I want each time. For example at the beginning I did it with arrays: char src[4] {0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x20}; char dst[4] {0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x60}; So later I putted them in a char[8] array. Next for example I added a char[64] array with more data.

Comment: So what you need is actually std::string, or a std::vector<char> as the element type.