# deprecated string constant to char conversion warning in CPP

Tags: c++

i'm trying the below basic program, where i'm getting a warning on compailing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class employee
{
private:
    char name[20];
    int age;
    float sal;
public:
    void setdata (char *n, int a, float s)
    {
        strcpy (name, n);
        age = a;
        sal = s;
    }
    void showdata()
    {
        cout << endl << name << '\t' << age << '\t' << sal << endl;
    }
};


int main ()
{

    employee e1;

    e1.setdata("ajay", 23, 4500.50);
    e1.showdata();
    return 0;
}
```

But, as soon as i compile this i get the below error;

`deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]`

Please explain why am i getting this error, and also the resolution to eliminate. and how dose the resolution works..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21529194/1708801)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , only the title is identical,.. doubt and code are totally different, can you help me understand whats happening here and how to correct it..??

Comment: @LazyShetty The code is always different, but the problem is the same. You are missing `const` in front of `char *n` in `setdata`.

Comment: yes it solved the warning.

Comment: but does this means "if i'm assigning value received as an argument to a constant pointer (in this case "name") then i must mention the const with the argument (like const char *n)"..??