# Can't get pass C++ warning: (& crash after) deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c++, codeblocks, dev-c++, bgi

I tried everything, and I can't even start this simple graph code. I have installed the graphics.h, winbgim.h  and libbgi.a in all the right folders. (include and lib). Linkers, too  -lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32

I'm using CodeBlocks 16.01. I have also tried it in Dev-C++ with no luck.

First I got error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\graphics.h|302|error: redefinition of 'int right'

But I solved that by changing the graphics.h file, `int right` needs to be replaced with `int top`.

Also there is 1 warning -

> C:\Users\Davor\Desktop\New Project\drugi\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
>   C:\Users\Davor\Desktop\New Project\drugi\main.cpp|15|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
>   ||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

After that, when I press 'Build and run' i get

> " *.exe has stopped working. "
>   In the background I first get -
>
> Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 91.666 s
>   Press any key to continue.

But every other time I get -

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 26.494 s
>   Press any key to continue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <graphics.h>


using namespace std;



int main() {

    int gdriver = 9;
    int gmode = 2;
    int x;
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
    setbkcolor (WHITE);
    setcolor (BLACK);
    cleardevice();
    for (x = 260; x < 364; x = x + 5)
    {
        circle(x,240,60);
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the third argument in `initgraph` is path, which you have kept empty, how will it load the driver then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char\*’ \[-Wwrite-strings\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529194/c-warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-wwrite-stri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The problem was in the next library:

> libbgi.a

I have tried sever different ones, but at the end I found the right one. As soon as I replaced it with the old one - the graphic window opened and worked just fine, without crashes.

The warning:

> deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
>   [-Wwrite-strings]|

is still there, but the code works perfectly.

Thanks for help anyway.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Without looking inside `<graphics.h>`, It would appear that `initgraph()` is declared as taking a (non-const) char* as the third parameter - suggesting that it is an *output* parameter, pointing to a writeable char array that `initgraph()` will write to.</del>

<del>As well as producing the warning you've quoted, passing the string constant `""` as the argument would result in undefined behaviour, of which crashing is a perfect example.</del>

While my remarks above are valid, after looking at the documentation I would surmise that the parameter is *not* an output parameter, and that the lack of `const` is simply poor API implementation - as is the apparent absence of any means to determine whether initialisation actually succeeded or not...

Comment: Any thoughts on how to resolve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: More helpfully, I would direct you to the statement in (what I assume is) the documentation that says "if pathtodriver is null, the driver files (*.BGI) must be in the current directory".

Comment: I have foun the solution, and posted the answer. Anyway, thanks for your time and help!